# Full page figures using RevTeX?

Tags: floats, positioning, revtex

I am typesetting an article using the `revtex4-2` document class (using the `twocolumn` option), and I was wondering if there is any way I can get a figure to be placed on its own separate page, like it is possible using the `\begin{figure}[p]` option in other document classes. (RevTeX seems to be ignoring the `[p]` option entirely.)

Background: I have a few tall figures in my document, which—in case there is no more space for regular text on the page—result in the following error:

```
Output routine didn't use all of \box255.
```

which causes the figure to not be typeset at all (instead, I get an empty page). The following MWE should illustrate the problem:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{tall-figure.tex}
    \documentclass[crop, tikz]{standalone}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            % For a height of 20, everything is fine:
            \draw (0, 0) rectangle (10, 21);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \begin{figure*}
        \includestandalone{tall-figure}
        \caption{Dummy Caption}
        \label{fig:dummy}
    \end{figure*}
    \lipsum[5-10]
\end{document}
```

Any hints and suggestions how to get full page figures with RevTeX would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing and facing the same problem. Hopefully an answer exists..

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Help would be appreciated